# injectivity of inl and inr in standard library

Tags: coq

Where in the Coq standard library can I find a lemma stating that `inl` and `inr` are injections?  That is, `forall (A B : Type)(x y : A), inl B x = inl B y -> x = y`, and analogously for the right-hand case.  I don't have a problem proving this by myself, but these seem like such useful and important lemmas to have that I have to imagine they are already in the standard library somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all constructors of inductive types are injective, it would be quite a hassle to define all those lemmas. Arguably, they could be defined automatically the way the induction principles are defined, but, they can be derived from them.

Anyway, if your need for the lemma is to make profress in a different proof, you should know about the tactic [injection](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic84), which retrieves all the necessary equalities for you.

Comment: I did not know about the injection tactic.  That looks like exactly what was needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a benefit to doing this over `inversion`?